# How to derive Eq.(4.26) from Eq. (4.25) in Birger Bergersen's book on Equilibrium Statistical Mechanics third Edition?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, equilibrium

This is a question from Maier-Saupe model section in the book.

Eq. (4.25) is:
$$(4.25)\ \ \ g=G/N=-k_BT\ln(4\pi\int_0^1 d\mu \exp\{\rho U \beta [(3\mu^2-1)Q-Q^2]\})$$
Eq. (4.26) is:
$$(4.26) \ \ \ g= G/N = -k_B T \ln(4\pi)+\rho U Q^2(1-\frac{2}{5}\beta \rho U)-\frac{8}{105}\beta^2\rho^3 U^3 Q^3 + \frac{4}{175}\beta^3 \rho^4U^4Q^4+\ldots . $$

For the life of me I don't see how to derive it, Birger et al. says it's now straightforward matter to obtain a Taylor expansion of (4.25) in powers of $Q$.

So I assumed I need to expand the exponential i.e with: $\exp(\rho U\beta[(3\mu^2-1)Q-Q^2])=1+\rho U\beta [ (3\mu^2-1)Q-Q^2]+(\rho U \beta [(3\mu^2-1)Q-Q^2])^2/2$ and then to use integration of $\mu$ and expand $\ln(ab)=\ln a + \ln b$, this is how we get the first term in (4.26), but I don't see how to get the other terms.

Can anyone lend some help with this derivation?
Thanks!

Comment: This should work, just keep more terms in your expansions both of the exponential and the logarithm (to go to order $\rho^4U^4Q^4$ as they do, you'll need to go up to fourth order both when expanding the exponential and the logarithm; of course, you can ignore all higher order terms appearing in your computations).

Comment: Of course, this is just a boring and painful (albeit straightforward) computation, so you could just as well let your computer do it...